# add class to only elements that contain <form>, <input />, or <select> with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add a class, .focused, to members of the class .dataCard that contain either one or more `<form>`, `<input />`, or `<select>`.

I was please pleased to learn of jQuery's `.has()` function, but that doesn't seem to be working.

Here is my code:

`$('.dataCard').has('form, input, select').addClass('focused');`

Why doesn't this add the class focused to .dataCard s that have form, inputs, or selects as inside as children?

And how can I do just that? Add a class of .focused to .dataCard s that have form, input, or select ?

Comment: Looks correct. Make sure it's running after they are loaded into the dom and also inspect the source to make sure the class really isn't being added. Maybe .focused isn't being styled as you expect.

Comment: When you say *contain*, do you mean  *are the parent of* or *are an ancestor of*?

Comment: @Rob It is in a document.ready and at the end before the closing body. All the other jQuery is working fine.

Comment: @Oriol By contain I mean it is anywhere inside the .dataCard element. There could be 50 divs wrapping the form, but as long as it is inside the .dataCard, that .dataCard is given the .focused class

Comment: @Rob Just checked the source. It is not working.

Comment: Can we see an example? See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dCYCe/, everything works as I think you are expecting.

Comment: And you are not choosing view source right? you have to inspect element, since it is dynamically added.

Comment: Alert has function with each element. Hobe it help.

Comment: @James Nope, I am inspecting the element and it is not adding the class.